# when I'm trying to run in flutter project, but receiving the below warning

Tags: flutter, dart, warnings

how to fix this warning?

Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/co
mmon/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/0
1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is related to `buildToolsVersion`. Try downgrading its version:

1. Go to app > build.gradle
2. Right under `compileSdkVersion`, change `buildToolsVersion("30.0.3")` to `buildToolsVersion("30.0.2")`

If you don't find any `buildToolsVersion` inside your gradle file, please add it. (It uses the new version by default).